# Passing array to parameter in NUnit test

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm learning C# and trying to pass an array as an argument (which is fine in my code but I cannot seem to create the `TestCase` for it in NUnit. My files are:

Walk.cs:

```
using System;

namespace TenMinWalk
{
    public class Walk
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        public string Walking(Array[] newWalk)
        {
            if (newWalk.Length == 10)
            {
                return "true";
            }
            return "false";
        }

    }
}
```

WalkTests.cs:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using TenMinWalk;

namespace TenMinWalkTests
{
    public class TenMinWalkTests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        public void WalkMustOnlyLast10Minutes()
        {
            Walk walk = new Walk();
            string actual = walk.Walking(['w', 's', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'w']);
            string expected = "true";
            Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);

        }
    }
}
```

In my test file, the error shown is: `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'newWalk' of 'Walk.Walking(Array[])'`

I have searched other answers and can see how to pass an array to a function but cannot seem to work out how to do this correctly in my Test file. Can anyone help please? (Sorry if this question is very basic but I'm very new to C#)

Thank you!

Comment: Change signature to `public string Walking(char[] newWalk)` and then `walk.Walking(new[] { 'w', 's', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'w' })`

Comment: `Array[]` is an **array of arrays**. Are you **sure** you want that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing `Array[]` in your Walking() method pass instance of `char array`.
like,

```
public string Walking(char[] newWalk)
   {
        if (newWalk.Length == 10)
        {
            return "true";
        }
        return "false";
   }
```

While passing it from NUnit test, create instance of char array and pass it as a parameter to function.

Like,

```
    [Test]
    public void WalkMustOnlyLast10Minutes()
    {
        Walk walk = new Walk();
        var charArray = new char[] {'w', 's', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'w'};
        string actual = walk.Walking(charArray);
        string expected = "true";
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);

    }
```

Honestly speaking, I would pass direct count instead of passing entire array as you are just checking length of an array.

something like,

```
   public bool Walking(int newWalkCount)
    {
        return newWalkCount == 10;
    }
```

In NUnit,

```
    [Test]
    public void WalkMustOnlyLast10Minutes()
    {
        Walk walk = new Walk();
        var charArray = new char[] {'w', 's', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'w'};

        //Passing length instead of entire array. Checking Assert.IsTrue()
        Assert.IsTrue(walk.Walking(charArray.Length));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much @PrasadTelkikar - I changed to the char array as suggested and this worked, however I continued to pass the entire array as later I want to implement a function which involves checking whether the elements in the array match. Thank you :)

Comment: @juemura7, I am glad that my solution works for you